# java.lang.StackOverflowError due to iterator in DFS

Tags: java, recursion, iterator, stack-overflow

I am currently trying to make a graph represantation of a game by creating the graph class by myself.
The constructor is this one (hope I dont have any logic mistake here):

```
 private int nNodes; 
    private int nEdges;
    private List<Integer> adj[];
    private boolean visited[];

    public GameGraph()
    {
        nNodes = 81;
        adj = new LinkedList[nNodes];
        for(int i = 0; i < nNodes; i++)
            adj[i] = new LinkedList();
        visited = new boolean[nNodes];
    }
```

I check if there is a path between a source and destination by using the depth first search algorithm. This is what I wrote:

```
 public boolean hasPath(int source , int dest)
        {
            if(source >= nNodes)
                return false;
            else
            {
                visited[source] = true;

                try
                {
                    Iterator<Integer> iterator = adj[source].listIterator();
                    while(iterator.hasNext())
                    {
                        int n = iterator.next();
                        if(n == dest)
                            return true;
                        visited[n] = true;
                        if(hasPath(n, dest))
                            return true;
                    }//end while
                    return false;
                }//end try
                catch(NullPointerException exception)
                {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }//end catch

                return false;
            }//end else
        }//end method has path
```

The problem is that when I run this method in a main class , I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedList.listIterator(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractList.listIterator(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractSequentialList.iterator(Unknown Source)
    at logic.GameGraph.hasPath(GameGraph.java:67)
    at logic.GameGraph.hasPath(GameGraph.java:74)at logic.GameGraph.hasPath(GameGraph.java:74)
    at logic.GameGraph.hasPath(GameGraph.java:74)
    at logic.GameGraph.hasPath(GameGraph.java:74)
```

line 67 is:

```
   Iterator<Integer> iterator = adj[source].listIterator();
```

And line 74 is the recursive call:

```
if(hasPath(n, dest))
```

I read about StackOverflowError and it had something to do with lack of memory available , I understand that one and my question is not that. But I don't understand why it should happen here cause of the iterator. I tried it even with nodes that are close to each other which make just a few recursive calls, and the same error occurs.

Comment: You never check wether or not you have alraedy visited the node. You only mark it as viisited, but when you encounter it again you check it again => infinite recursion.

Comment: Add a `println()` statement at the beginning of method `hasPath()`, printing both parameters. The output will help identify why your code fails. This is called **debugging**. You might also want to read "[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5221149)", though a simple `print` statement is likely the easier way to see the problem.

Comment: @Polygnome yes you are right , thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before going into recursive call check if you have already covered that node by using

```
....
int n = iterator.next();
if(!visited[n]){
...
}
```